# Impact wrench on spark plugs?

Tags: sparkplugs, tools

'07 Cobalt LS, vanilla 2.2

I may have to remove the (probably 10-year-old) spark plugs, which I suspect may be stuck.  If so, I'm wondering if it would be prudent to hit them with an impact wrench to break them free.

Comment: Side thought - make sure your spark plug socket is a decent fit - minor tolerance variations can rob you of torque.  Compare a removed plug with your socket.  And use anti-seize when fitting new plugs.

Comment: Is there actually a problem here or is this premature optimization?

Comment: In the end IF they will not come out using wrenches you may have to use an impact carefully, they have an advantage of creating vibrations which help loosen frozen threads, its better if the engine is very hot when attempting removal of the stuck spark plugs. If they are truly seized in the head, it does not mater what method removes them the threads will get pulled out with the plug.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In a word:

### NO!

Please do not use an impact wrench on these. You run the distinct chance of stripping out all of the threads in the head, which will cause a huge nightmare for you having to have threads replaced (Heli-coil or the like). Just use a socket/ratchet and you'll be fine.

Comment: Or snapping off the body and leaving the plug threads in the hole...

Comment: If you are having trouble use some penetrating fluid like WD40, and give it time. Engina the goddess of motors will not be happy with you if you use an impact wrench on spark plugs.

Comment: @GdD My tried-and-true formula for loosening any threaded object has always been some combination of heat, PB Blaster, and time.

Comment: @GdD Since spark plugs have gas tight seals above the threads, is there really any chance that something like wd40 will help?

Comment: Sometimes it's the seals that seize @HandyHowie

Comment: @HandyHowie Given enough time (several days) WD40 will eat away some of the seal material. It is really nasty stuff. Just spray some more WD40 on every day and give it 3-4 days.

Comment: @Tonny most spark plugs I've seen has some sort of metallic seals. WD40 is ***not*** corrosive, and will ***not*** eat away the seals. It may penetrate the seal if it's not perfect, however.

Comment: @vidarlo WD40 is corrosive to a greater or lesser degree to any plastic and/or rubber compound. If you've got full metal seals that doesn't make a difference but in many case there is some washer or grommet that isn't metalk.

Comment: @Tonny - It has not been my experience WD40 will degrade plastics to any degree. I know it can swell rubber (natural rubber) if the rubber is soaked in it over time, but that's not degrading the rubber itself. Do you have any real references about this?

Comment: If you have trouble getting the plugs out of a dead cold engine, it sometimes helps to run the engine until it's just barely warmed up, but not hot, and try again.

Comment: @Tonny not seen any spark plugs with plastic seals or rubber ones.. spark plugs have metal compressible washers to make the seal.

Comment: WD40 is not penetrating and is not for breaking loose stuck threads! Use something like Pb Blaster, Liquid Wrench, etc. that's actually made for the job.

Comment: @MTA also, a hot air gun can help with localised heating, if the engine isn't startable.

Comment: Penetrating oils have been proven not to help at all, and wd40 is not a penetrating oil.

Comment: @Jesse_b got a citation for penetrating oils being proven useless?

Comment: @DanNeely: [here](https://youtu.be/YeTNXbDbHcM) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUEob2oAKVs) and [here](https://youtu.be/st8dkGzJWtg).  Also [here](https://youtu.be/dObEK7V-TFU) and [here](https://youtu.be/2G-dX50JuXE).  Every test shows marginal or absolutely no difference at all between the control and every type of oil tested.  The only things that work are heat and a little tappy tap tap.

Answer (score 5):

Use PB Blaster(the BEST),NOT WD-40(Water Displacement Formulation 40) or any brand of penetrating solvent,Liquid Wrench,etc. An impact wrench is a formula for disaster. Use a breaker bar to get the plug to move just a bit is good,apply more penetrant and,hard as it may to do so,WAIT. Days,even.If you can get the plug to move, even a bit counter-clockwise,re tighten it clockwise,then back the other way. Do this many times to slowly work the plug out. Be aware,muscling it out counterclockwise without going back and forth.counterclockwise,then clockwise, MAY damage the head beyond use. This is especially true of aluminum heads. Due to the plug threads reaching INTO the combustion chamber,Triton engines are very prone to damage when removing plugs. No matter what method is used on these engines,the head may be scrap when removing the plugs are attempted. By ANYONE,period.